# Is it possible, to see hibernate`s queryPlanCache contents?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, memory-leaks

I got memory leak problem with queryPlaneCache in Hibernate 5.2.10.Final. I found information about leak troubles with IN() queries and marked them with setCacheable(false). Leak decreased, but not dissapeared.

I tried decrase **hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_size** and turn off caching (**hibernate.cache.use_query_cache**). It helps, but i think this is no right solution. I want mark some problem queries as setCacheable(false) and save cache mechanism in good work, but don`t have some things about trouble queries.

By this reason i want dump a queryPlaneCache content for see concrete SQL queries and found source of problem. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you refer to when you say `memory leak` - an `OutOfMemory error`? Is it enough for you to print the content of said cache or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Yes, it's OutOfMemory. I get heap dump and see in MAT a big count of queryPlaneCache rows. Yes, i want print this cache for see which queries a get a lot of space there. For example, may be i skip one query with big volatile IN() and it's born this error.

Comment: You are using `ehcache` as a provider? I know you can configure the cache to be written to the harddisk (but I don't remember whether it was a readable format) and (at least in older hibernate versions) it was possible to get access to the cache programmaticly and print out its content from there.

Comment: If you do please also mention the version you are using and whether you have a configuration file for it or not. If not name what provider and what version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, if you're ok with a little reflection to access private fields. This is how I did it. getQueryPlanCacheDump() returns a list of strings representing the cached queries, the other information stored in the cache is discarded (its likely not necessary for diagnosing your issue)

When I did it, I found that my cache was filling up due to the `IN` clause caching a new query plan each time they query was used with a different number of parameters.

```java
  private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  public List<String> getQueryPlanCacheDump() {
    try (var session = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class)) {
      var sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImpl) session.getSessionFactory();
      return getQueryList(sessionFactory);
    }
  }

  private List<String> getQueryList(SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory) {
    BoundedConcurrentHashMap<?, ?> queryPlanCache = getQueryPlanCache(sessionFactory);
    var queries = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
      var hqlQueryPlanKeyClazz = Class.forName("org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache$HQLQueryPlanKey");
      var filterQueryPlanKeyClazz = Class.forName("org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache$FilterQueryPlanKey");
      queryPlanCache.forEach((key, value) -> {
        // The cache contains 3 different types of keys
        if (key instanceof NativeSQLQuerySpecification nativeSql) {
          queries.add(nativeSql.getQueryString());
        } else if (hqlQueryPlanKeyClazz.isInstance(key)) {
          queries.add(getQuery(hqlQueryPlanKeyClazz, key));
        } else if (filterQueryPlanKeyClazz.isInstance(key)) {
          queries.add(getQuery(filterQueryPlanKeyClazz, key));
        }
      });
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // If Hibernate adds more key types in the future, return all the key types instead so you can investigate adding support for them
      var keyClasses = new HashSet<String>();
      queryPlanCache.forEach((key, value) -> keyClasses.add(key.getClass().toString()));
      return keyClasses.stream().toList();
    }
    return queries;
  }

  private String getQuery(Class<?> clazz, Object key) {
    try {
      var queryField = clazz.getDeclaredField("query");
      queryField.setAccessible(true);
      return (String) queryField.get(key);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
  }

  private BoundedConcurrentHashMap<?, ?> getQueryPlanCache(SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory) {
    try {
      var queryPlanCacheField = QueryPlanCache.class.getDeclaredField("queryPlanCache");
      queryPlanCacheField.setAccessible(true);
      return (BoundedConcurrentHashMap<?, ?>) queryPlanCacheField.get(sessionFactory.getQueryPlanCache());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
  }
```